# obfsproxy running on centos 7

Tags: centos7, python

I am using CentOS 7 os.
I installed python3.6 on this machine.
pip3 is latest version 21.
After that i installed obfsproxy like this :

> To use obfsproxy you will need Python (>= 2.7) and pip.

```
pip3 install pathlib
pip3 install pyopenssl
pip3 install Twisted
pip3 install obfsproxy
```

Here are installation path :

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.13-py3.6.egg-info

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/obfsproxy

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/obfsproxy/pyobfsproxy.py

> /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy

Now after running obfsproxy command i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/obfsproxy", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('obfsproxy==0.2.13', 'console_scripts', 'obfsproxy')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 476, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2700, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/obfsproxy/pyobfsproxy.py", line 183
    except ValueError, err:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@blobloblo ~]# obfsproxysite-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 476, in load_entry_point
```

What version of python is suitable for this script and how can i fix this error?
I tried some older python versions.
Buy manual installation has some error and this is better to install python3 from default repository.
Mean for install python3 i did this :

> centos is updated totally.

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release

sudo yum install -y libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
gcc --version

openssl version
openssl version -d

sudo yum install -y openssl-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel bzip2-devel
sudo yum install -y make automake gcc glibc
sudo yum install -y gcc

python -V
python --version
python2 -V
python3 -V

sudo yum install python3
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

---

Here is https://pypi.org/project/obfsproxy/ link.

Comment: Centos 7, whilst still supported is getting somewhat out of date. You will find the golang version of [obfs4](https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4) proxy will be easier to build, install and maintain. It supports obfs version 3 and 4 using the same binary and can handle botn versions (on separate ports) at the same time.

Comment: Where can i download executeable client of that script for windows os?

Comment: I don't use Windows. If you configure your C7 server to use the golang binary in obfs3 mode, your existing Windows obfs3 client should work with it. YOu coukld always try compiling it on Windows too, it'll probably just work as expected.

Comment: What about obfs4? Does it work?

Comment: It works as an obfuscated proxy for sure. Whether it will do what you want, only you can determine.